# How to get file mask instead of array of files when running jar from console?

Tags: java

I've faced strange thing: when i run jar file with "java -jar my.jar acc*", where "acc*" is file mask, in my main()'s string array i get all file names starting with "acc" but not the mask itself. Why? And how can i get my file mask?

Comment: Your OS is expanding this symbol to match all files that start with `acc`. You either need to escape it or enclose into quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
java -jar my.jar "acc*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can also try:

```
java -jar my.jar acc\*
```

This should also work fine.

Comment: no, it doesn't. In this case i get exactly "acc\\*" and not "acc*"

Comment: But I tried on my machine :O (not with a jar though, just the Java class file.